# Should I use Magic Lantern as a beginner?

Tags: dslr, magic-lantern

I'm getting a Canon 600 D. I will also get a 32 gb class 10 sd card. Do you think I shoujld get another card and install Magic Lantern into that?

I really want to create time lapses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone who just went through the transition of using Canon firmware to Magic Lantern firmware, no. It depends ENTIRELY on what you know. For instance, do you know what shutter speed, ISO, and aperture are? Do you know what effect shooting "wide open" or with a high ISO has on your shot? Do you know how to correctly set your white balance and get correct exposure?

If you're a beginner and you're not familiar with these terms, you may at first be overwhelmed; that's totally normal and OK. But, it is my strong suggestion that you get to know these things and work with the standard Canon firmware before moving to Magic Lantern. Film making is hard enough as it is, no point in making it more difficult on yourself. Once you have a strong grasp of the basics, you can better appreciate/utilize the features that Magic Lantern gives you (recording formats, focus peaking, settings logs, RGB parade, hotkeys, wider range of ISO/aperture values, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I would disagree with Scott on this.  I think ML is great for starting out doing video for a beginner, but you need to be sure to read the ML forums to learn about the features it offers you.

DSLR video is not easy.  It is far more complicated than shooting video on a consumer camera and getting good results requires skills you don't have yet.  Magic Lantern provides tools (such as focus peaking and zebra) that will help you considerably as you are learning to shoot video on your DSLR.

Yes, there are a TON of options in ML and so it can be easy to get overwhelmed, but that is why reading their tutorials and forums, and also why asking about the use of certain features here on Video Production is a great option.

**Particularly since you mentioned time lapse, Magic Lantern also provides intervolometer functionality for capturing time lapse sequences as well.**

Comment: The intervalometer bonus is a good mention. I know for me, personally, I was so overwhelmed by pre-production, production, and post-production that to add on the complexity of ML would of probably killed me, haha. You have to learn a lot as a beginner film maker and ML at that time was too much for me. Now, however, it's a god send.

Comment: @ScottJamesWalter - yeah, the trick is to look for specific features rather than trying to learn all the bells and whistles, because ML gives you an orchestra.